# Usage of adjectives after noun

Tags: adjectives

> 1. I found a boy asleep.
> 2. I found a asleep boy.

Which is correct? My grammar book says sentence one is correct and sentence two is wrong. Why so?

Comment: "asleep" is not an attributive adjective, (but predicative?).

Comment: Asleep is a predicative adjective. Predicative adverbs can't be used in the attributive position. https://www.lexico.com/grammar/attributive-and-predicative-adjectives

Comment: @OldBrixtonian  But how to know which adjective is predicative ?

Comment: @Cardinal How to know which adjective is attributive and which adjective is predicative?

Comment: @ramteja guthikond Most adjectives can be used attributively AND predicatively: the tall man/the man is tall. But some can only be used before a noun, and others only after a copular verb (he IS asleep, they are alike) or a perception verb (he doesn't look well; he seems afraid)ablaze
abreast
afire
afloat
afraid
aghast
aglow
alert
alike
alive
alone
aloof
ashamed (Note that some Englishes allow for attributive use of ashamed.)
asleep
awake
aware

Comment: @ramtejaguthikonda Just practicing and memorizing the patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Most adjectives can be used attributively AND predicatively:

```
the tall man/the man is tall
```

But some can only be used attributively (ie before a noun)

```
that is the main reason [Not 'that reason is main']
```

Others can only be used after a **copular** verb

```
he was asleep, they are alike
```

or a **perception** verb

```
he doesn't look well, he seems afraid
```

It might be easiest to learn those adjectives which can only be used predicatively.

Many of them have an a-suffix: ablaze, abreast, afloat, afraid, aghast, alike, alive, alone, aloof, ashamed, asleep, awake, aware

Answer (score 0):

Asleep is slightly unusual, most adjectives can go before a noun or after a linking verb:

> He is a happy boy  / The boy is happy.

Asleep always goes after the verb, and also after any direct objects of that verb

> The boy is asleep / I found the boy asleep.

You know it is a [predicative adjective](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825045158/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/attributive-and-predicative-adjectives) because the [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/asleep) tells you.

Comment: What is the difference between “The navigable roads” and “The roads naviable”?

Comment: @  ramteja guthikond Please read the very simple and helpful guide at the link I provided.